# UIView Curled Corner animated effect

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, opengl-es, core-animation

I want to create a special animation effect applied to a UIView, similar to the famous curly effect but just for a top corner on a selected UIView.

This the effect I want to accomplish (programmatically and animated of course):

[image]

The best approach I've found is [W. Dana Nuon's](http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html).

Comment: can to tell me how you accomplished this?

Comment: I finally decided to overlap an UIImageView with image sequences for curling down and curling up, and it looked pretty good (the render was done in Photoshop).
But because the project may had tones of those post-it, I just did a switch of two images state.

Comment: You mean a series of images to give a `.gif` image like effect?

Comment: Yep. Except that they are not GIFs but PNGs.
UIImageView has animation APIs where you stack UIImages and start/stop the sequence as you like.

Comment: OK...got it...thanks...I am trying to do something like this [(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625957/animate-while-curling-a-corner-of-uiimageview-using-a-masking-method)]. Any suggestions..

Comment: Well, you would not achieve that effect animated if the method you are using is returning a single UIImage.
What you may do, is to calculate each frame of the curl and return a new UIImage until the animation is done. It might be a little bit of work.
Like I told you, I didn't find a better solution than adding a sequence of UIImages to the UIImageView...

Answer (score 0):

CAFilter is a private, undocumented class in iOS (and remains stubbornly so!), so any use of it would be rejected.  There are, of course, [transforms and little core graphics quirks](http://www.giderosmobile.com/blog/2012/02/02/howto-impressive-pagecurl-effect-gideros-studio/) that can be applied to the layer (in order to achieve an animated effect), however the easiest route, in my opinion, would be to make the curl an image that you could then overlay.  It is, after all, nice and perfectly square:

[image: Nice and perfectly square]

Comment: Thank you CodaFi for pointing to that interesting public API, but it didn't really applied to my request.

The best I've found so far is CoreAnimation's CAFilter class, but it results to be "once again" a private class. http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CAFilter#pageCurl It looks like you can really customize the pageCurl filter and animated it, but I wonder if Apple will reject an app doing in that. What do you think?

Comment: Any app built using the leaves page curl will not be rejected.  There are several already on the app store!

Comment: I meant the use of the private class CAFilter. It might be a risk to take if the effect runs nice and smooth. I'm working on it, I will be posting if I get a nice result.

Comment: Most certainly, yes.  Any app built with undocumented or private API's from apple (or any 3rd party) will be rejected.  It's a safety and consistency thing, not an anal retentive thing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you CodaFi for pointing to that interesting public API, but it didn't really applied to my request.

The best I've found so far is CoreAnimation's CAFilter class, but it results to be "once again" a private class. http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CAFilter#pageCurl
It looks like you can really customize the pageCurl filter and animated it, but I wonder if Apple will reject an app doing in that.
What do you think?